# How to care for neck strap?

Tags: equipment-protection, accessories, maintenance

I have a wide neck strap that came with my DSLR. In the two years, it racked a lot of hours soaking in sweat and some light rain/snow.

To the professionals who lug their neck strap through thick and thin, how do you care for it? And what NOT to do.

I have searched unsuccessfully for previous question on neck strap care. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I don't do anything. You get a new one when you buy a new camera body, and if you like third party ones that are more comfortable, they only cost $30 and buying one every few years when they wear isn't a concern to me. I don't _care_ for mine at all and I don't think it is necessary to.

Comment: dpollitt, thank for sharing. Now I feel better instead of feeling bad from focusing only on caring for the L lens and body, neglecting the neck strap.

Comment: I retired mine and got a handstrap instead... so liberating! :)

Comment: Michael, which handstrap would you recommend for a 7D with 70-200 f2.8 IS USM. They're quick heavy straining both the neck strap and the neck. Thanks.

Comment: @dpollitt: I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I have a noname cheapo one "2 point" version (similar to Canons own) for my 40D with battery grip, which with speedlite 430EX II can be pretty heavy. Nikon makes a "3point" version which is better for lengthy operation, but they are pretty expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since neck straps are more or less disposable most people don't mind if they break. Knock-offs can be had on ebay for a few dollars. The stock cannon ones last ages (I've had one for more than 5 years now and no issue aside from cosmetics).

If you want to go the way of a 3rd party neck strap i reccomend the unfortunately named 'R-strap' from black-rapid. See [here](http://www.blackrapid.com/). It makes a 5D with 70-200mm feel like its half the weight!

However, if your super keen on your strap, the following is how i clean my climbing rope :P So you it should work wonders for your neck-strap as well. (Rope needs to be maintained so the rope doesn't fail when you fall)

To clean your neck strap wash occasionally by hand in warm water with a mild soap, rinse free of the soap, and then hung up to dry in the air. 
Avoid direct sunlight, do not use a dryer, and do not place the neck strap above a heat source.
If you can, the strap should be stored, preferably after drying, at room temperature, ideally in a storage bag.

The only thing i don't do with my straps is take them caving/crawling through mud. I've got a couple of pieces of climbing tape/rope for that if i need them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, especially on the cleaning tips which are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I retired mine and got a hand strap instead... it is so liberating.

I use a noname version of this (below) for a 40D with battery grip and often a speedlite 430EX II, which can get pretty heavy. The pad on it allows you to relax your arm and hand without dropping it.

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-Hand-Strap-E1-Review.aspx

But with your very long and heavy lens you might want to go for this 3-point support from Nikon:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Nikon-AH-4-Leather-Hand-Grip-Review.aspx